# How can I explode a nested dictionary into a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary as below. I'm trying to convert the below to a dataframe with the columns iid, Invnum, @type, execId, CId, AId, df, type. What’s the best way to go about it?

```
data = {'A': {'B1': {'iid': 'B1', 'Invnum': {'B11': {'@type': '/test_data', 'execId': 42, 'CId': 42, 'AId': 'BAZ'}, 'B12': {'@type': '/test_data', 'CId': 8, 'AId': '123'}}}}, 'B2': {'iid': 'B2', 'Invnum': {'B21': {'@type': '/test_data', 'execId': 215, 'CId': 253,'df': [], 'type': 'F'}, 'B22': {'@type': '/test_data', 'execId': 10,'df': [], 'type': 'F'}}}}


for key1 in data['A'].keys():
    for key2 in data['A'][key1]['Invnum']:
        print(key1,key2)
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: In `Invnum` you have another nested `dict`, how do you want to put it into DataFrame, as `dict`? Also these `B1` and `B2` are variables. You're trying to do something evil.

Comment: Is `data` intended as json? (I'm guessing based on the use of `@type`). `pandas` has a built-in [`read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) that could be helpful.

Comment: Apologies, updated above with expected output.

Comment: @dash2186 yeah. But if we don't know the contents of `B1` and `B2` variables, we can not track the names. If you do `data['A']['B1']['iid']` you'll never know it's a `B1` variable. One could use [locals()](https://www.codespeedy.com/get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python/) to get the name, but without it's value, we'll never know.

Comment: Kk, disregard the last comment, question was edited.

Comment: Related (it covers program input and output as well): *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*

Comment: I think the structure of the dictionary in your example is incorrect or incomplete, can you post more data?

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, your input data is very obscure. This provides a lot of trouble for us, because we don't know what we can assume or not. For my solution I will assume at least the following, based on the example you provide:

1. In the dictionary there is an entry containing the `iid` and `Invnum` as keys in the same level.
2. The `Invnum` key is the **only** key, which has multiple values, or in otherwords is iterable (besides `df`), and on iteration it **must hold** the last dictionary. In otherwords, after the `Invnum` value (e.g. `B11`), you can only get the last dict with the other fields as keys (`@type`, `execId`, `CId`, `AId`, `df`, `type`), if they exists.
3. If there is a `df` value, it will hold a `list`.

```
# This is a place holder dictionary, so we can create entries that have the same pattern.
entry = {'@type': '', 'execId': '', 'CId': '', 'AId': '', 'df': '', 'type': ''}

# This will hold all the (properly) format entries for the df.
items = []

def flatten(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        match data:
            # We are searching for a level that contains both an `iid` and `Invnum` key.
            case {'iid': id, 'Invnum': remainder}:
                for each in remainder:
                    entry_row = dict(**entry, iid=id, Invnum=each)
                    entry_row.update(remainder[each])
                    items.append(entry_row)
            case _:
                for key, value in data.items():
                    flatten(value)

# We flatten the data, such that the `items` variable will hold consistent entries
flatten(data)

# Transfer to pandas dataframe, and reorder the values for easy comparison.
df = pd.DataFrame(items)
df = df[['iid', 'Invnum', '@type', 'execId', 'CId', 'AId', 'df', 'type']]
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
iid Invnum      @type execId CId AId df type
 B1    B11 /test_data     42  42 BAZ        
 B1    B12 /test_data          8 123        
 B2    B21 /test_data    215 253     []    F
 B2    B22 /test_data     10         []    F
```

Note:

- All entries have been turned into strings, since I am using `''` for empty values.
- I heavily rely on the above made assumptions, in case they are incorrect, the answer will not match your expectation.
- I am using `Structural pattern matching`, which is introduced in python 3.10.

Comment: Given how quacked up the initial data is, this is definitely a plus. I have an older 3.9 Python version installed and I ended up with 20 lines of messed up code iterating through dictionaries recursively, counting rows and keeping track of column names to start a new row if a duplicate column name appears. I ended up with a perfect output but `iid` having spaces: `['B1', '', 'B2', '']`, so that could not be an answer to a question. But, I did not refer to `iid` and `invnum` in a function.

Comment: @DiMithras; The input data is indeed very complicated, and I hope they will clean that up. Credits to do it it in 3.9, it seems that your solution is more general, and the problem with the spaces in the iid, could be solved by repeating the value on the left of an empty space `''` . Since the data that is inside the `iid` seems to be repeating the value. Add the first value again to the `iid`, (`iid.insert(0, iid[0])`) so we can compare two elements at the same time by using `[second if second else first for first, second in zip(iid, iid[1:])]`, resulting in `['B1', 'B1', 'B2', 'B2']`.